# Android PreferenceScreen "color picker" implementation

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper, preferenceactivity

can someone help me? I need implement some color picker to preference screen (live wallpaper settings). Is there any solution out there, some open source?

Comment: Here's one that I found; https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference

Comment: thanks, and is there any tutorial about implementation?

Comment: It comes with a simple ``Test`` Activity you can use for reference on how to implement it into your own application.

Answer (score 14):

Too late for the original questioner I expect, but here's the library I wrote after not finding what I needed here. It can be used like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.rarepebble.colorpicker.ColorPreference
        android:key="myColor"
        android:title="@string/pref_title"
        android:defaultValue="#f00"
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

More info here:

[HSV-Alpha Color Picker for Android](https://github.com/martin-stone/hsv-alpha-color-picker-android) (GitHub).

[HSV-Alpha Color Picker Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarepebble.colorpickerdemo) (Google Play).

I hope it's useful for somebody else.

[image: ColorPreference] [image: Color Picker]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Plus it took around a minute to implement.

Comment: Fast and easy to implement :)

Answer (score 6):

If someone is looking for a great new android color picker that use material design I have forked an great project from github and made a simple-to-use android color picker dialog.

This is the project: [Android Color Picker](https://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog)

[image: Android Color Picker Example]

It's easy to implement by yourself. There is a complete android studio project ready to download for see how it works.

Answer (score 4):

you may check this:

[ColorPickerCollection](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/colorpickercollection)

If you want to let user choose on out of set of colors, you can use the ColorPickerCollection library.